# SH-B123 won't play BlurRay discs. Why?

Tags: blu-ray

I have a Samsung BD-ROM/DVD writer model SH-B123, but I am unable to play bluray movies that player shows the disc name and reads the disk but does not play the movie.

How can I fix this?

Comment: On what operating system? What program are you using to try to access the disc?

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using?  What playback software are you using?  You do realize that unlike DVDs, Blu-Ray support isn't baked into any mainstream OS and requires special software to watch commercial movies, right?

It's also possible you're trying to view HDCP content on a non-HDCP compliant device.  If you are using correct playback software, what is your video adapter and monitor, and how are they connected?

(If I'm misinterpreting your question, and you DO in fact have some playback app installed, and correct hardware, please edit the question to reflect this and myself or someone else can provide a better answer.)